# Expo error when trying to build: Unsupported SDK version: our app builders don't have support for 33.0.0 version

Tags: expo

When trying to build my Expo project, using `expo build:ios`, I get the following error:

> Unsupported SDK version: our app builders don't have support for
>   33.0.0 version yet. Submitting the app to the Apple App Store may result in an unexpected behaviour Unsupported SDK version

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## What causes this error?

This error is caused by the fact that as of March 31st 2020 the Expo client no longer supports Expo SDK 33. From the Expo release blog we see the following:

> ## Dropping SDK 33 from the Expo client
>
> We routinely drop SDK versions
>   that have low usage in order to reduce the number of versions that we
>   need to support. This release sees the end of life for SDK 33. As
>   usual, your standalone apps built with SDK 33 will continue to work;
>   however, SDK 33 projects will no longer work within the latest version
>   of the Expo client. If you want to re-run expo build, then you’ll need
>   to upgrade from SDK 33, preferably to SDK 37 so you won’t need to
>   update again for a while (and also because each Expo version is better
>   than the last!).

---

## How do I fix this?

To fix this error you need to upgrade the SDK that that your Expo project is using. Ideally you should upgrade to the latest version. In this case Expo SDK 37 as that will give you the longest amount of time until you have to upgrade again.

To upgrade the SDK. Expo has a fantastic resource detailing what you have to do [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/). Each blog post give steps on how to upgrade.

Here are the basic steps on how to upgrade:

- Run `expo upgrade` in your project directory (requires the latest version of `expo-cli`, you can update with `npm i -g expo-cli`).
- Make sure to check the [changelog](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for other breaking changes!
- Update the Expo app on your phones from the App Store / Google Play. `expo-cli` will automatically update your apps in simulators if you delete the existing apps, or you can run `expo client:install:ios` and `expo client:install:android`.
- If you built a standalone app previously, remember that you will need to create a new build in order to update the SDK version. Run `expo build:ios` and/or `expo build:android` when you are ready to do a new build for submission to stores.

---

## Make sure you check the changelogs

As you are upgrading from SDK 33 you will need to look at the different changelogs that exist for upgrading from 33 to 34, 34 to 35, 35 to 36, and finally 36 to 37. This is because there could be something that occurred in one of those updates that may break something in your app.

---

## How can I avoid this problem in the future?

Simply, make sure that you keep your apps up-to-date. Upgrading many versions of Expo and/or React-Native can be cumbersome as features are added and removed with each release. The easiest way to stay on top of it is to upgrade frequently, I find that by setting aside a coupe of days a month to check the dependencies etc that I am using are up-to-date means that I do not have to massive upgrades. It also means I am in a better place to know what it going to cause a problem and I have more time to fix it.

---

## tl;dr

Update your Expo SDK version to the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

Incompatible version of SDK..
For me, it worked after updating the Expo app from Google play store..